# What are the differences between illumos kernel CIFS, Linux kernel CIFS and Samba?

Tags: linux, samba, kernel, cifs

I'm aware of the [comparison](https://serverfault.com/questions/228338/native-smb-cifs-through-zfs-or-samba-instead) between kernel CIFS and Samba package in illumos.

What are the differences between illumos kernel CIFS and [Linux kernel CIFS](https://wiki.samba.org/index.php/LinuxCIFS)?

Moreover, I [read](http://wiki.robotz.com/index.php/Linux_CIFS_Utils_and_Samba) that kernel CIFS is the new preferred way, but Ubuntu still [talks about](https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/serverguide/samba-fileserver.html.en) installing Samba.

How do the three alternatives compare? Theoretically and in practical terms (including ACLs).

**Edit**: see also [Linux CIFS utils](https://wiki.samba.org/index.php/LinuxCIFS_utils):

> The in-kernel CIFS filesystem is generally the preferred method for
>   mounting SMB/CIFS shares on Linux.
>
> The in-kernel CIFS filesystem relies on a set of user-space tools.
>   That package of tools is called cifs-utils. Although not really part
>   of Samba proper, these tools were originally part of the Samba
>   package. For several reasons, shipping these tools as part of Samba
>   was problematic and it was deemed better to split them off into their
>   own package.

Comment: The Linux kernel does not have a CIFS server though...?

Comment: @DanielB then why is that (https://wiki.samba.org/index.php/LinuxCIFS_utils) "The in-kernel CIFS filesystem is generally the preferred method for mounting SMB/CIFS shares on Linux. The in-kernel CIFS filesystem relies on a set of user-space tools. That package of tools is called cifs-utils. Although not really part of Samba proper, these tools were originally part of the Samba package."

Comment: ? That description says it all: “for mounting”. Not for serving.

Comment: @DanielB thanks, I really didn't notice. I guess the question is of little significance now.